# Have two containers listen on same udp port

Tags: docker, udp

I have two applications that listen to port 3000 for UDP packets.  If I run them natively, all is well.

Now, I would like to put them in Docker containers.  But it appears that the process of publishing to port 3000 in the docker compose file like so:

```
ports:
  -"3000:3000/udp"
```

... creates an exclusive bind on the host's port 3000 such that the second container fails to publish its port.

Is there any way to allow two containers to do a non-exclusive bind to receive UDP traffic on the same port?  I'm wondering if there is some way to tell docker to set `SO_REUSEPORT` to true when it does the bind.

Or maybe there is some other way to do what I need?

Comment: is it really needed to have the port binding on the host port? normally if you have a multiple containers, each of them would expose the port 3000 and it would work fine since each container has its own ip